# Multi-Dimensional Arrays--> Null Object Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, null

I am trying to develop a C++ application. Part of the Application is meant to create and initiate some properties of an Object and then store the object in a multi-dimensional array. Problem is after Object creation and storing the objects in the array, retrieving the Object values gives me pointers to NULL.

Please see code below for exact implementation:

Cell** TestMain::convertToMatrix(){

```
//char[] lengthArr = arra[0];

//int[][] temp
int rowCount = getCurrentRowCount(); // Gives the row count of the multi-dimensional array
int colCount =  getCurrentColCount(); // Gives the column count of the multi-dimensional array

Cell** cellList;

cellList = new Cell*[rowCount];
for (int rowIter=rowCount-1;rowIter>=0; rowIter-- ){
    cellList[rowIter] = new Cell[colCount];
    for (int colIter=colCount-1;colIter>=0;colIter--) {
        Cell *currentCell = new Cell(arra[rowIter][colIter],rowIter,colIter);

        //Calculate weights
        if (0==currentCell->getValue()) currentCell->setWeight(0);
        if (1== currentCell->getValue()) {
            if (isEdge(rowIter,colIter)) {
                currentCell->setWeight(1);
            }
            else {
                //currentCell->setWeight(1 + getMinimumValue(cellList[rowIter+1][colIter]->getWeight(),cellList[rowIter+1][colIter+1]->getWeight(),cellList[rowIter][colIter+1]->getWeight() ) );
                currentCell->setWeight(1 + getMinimumValue(cellList[rowIter+1][colIter].getWeight(),cellList[rowIter+1][colIter+1].getWeight(),cellList[rowIter][colIter+1].getWeight() ) );
            }


        }

        cellList[rowIter][colIter] = *currentCell;
    }
}
return cellList;
```

}
`

Here is the code that performs the checking later in the code:

void StrawberryMain::printField(Cell** arrayOfCells) {

```
int row=0;
int column=0;

int maxRowCount= getCurrentRowCount();
int maxColCount = getCurrentColCount();


for (;row<maxRowCount;row++) {
    Cell *cellArr = arrayOfCells[row];
    for (;column<maxColCount;column++) {
        Cell currentArrayCell = cellArr[column];

        /*if (currentArrayCell==NULL){   // This line throws an error ->No match for ‘operator==’ in ‘currentArrayCell == 0’. Why?  
        printf("Returned Pointer for Cell was NULL");
        }
        else { */

            printf("%s(%s)|", currentArrayCell.getWeight(),currentArrayCell.getValue());
        /


    //}

    printf("\n");


}
```

}

When I run the program I get a whole load of `nulls` printed on my screen as output.( One null for every object supposed stored in the array

I come from a Java background ( although I have dabbled in QT C++ before) so I am a bit miffed why this is happening. As much as I would appreciate an answer I would value an explanation as to why this happens ( or a link which explains why this happens) as I really want to understand the workings of the Language.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Just some advice: Generally, it's helpful (to other users, and yourself) to attempt to reduce the size of your code snippets to the minimum amount that actually causes the bug.  It's easier to read and spot bugs, and you may end up finding the bug yourself in the process...

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html, and 
http://ublas.sourceforge.net/refdoc/

Comment: @Oli, I understand but I was caught between showing too much and not showing enough to identify the bug. I actually believed this wast the 'Minimum amount' to correctly seek help with. My apologies if it seems too much.

Comment: @aaa: I ideally would not want to use any external libraries. I was also contemplating using Vectors but wanted to use 'pure' C++ multi-dimensional arrays. Thanks none the less.

Comment: @Kris: Just to be pedantic, technically, this isn't a multi-dimensional array.  That would be something like `Cell blah[M][N]`.  What you have here is really just double indirection via pointers.

Comment: Incidentally, you have a big memory leak; nothing is deleting `currentCell` on each iteration of the inner loop in `TestMain::convertToMatrix()`.

Comment: @Oli:Post1, I know this is not a "REAL" multi-dimensional array, but I was led to believe that this is the best C++ offered. Was I deceived? As regarding the Memory leak, I was thinking of getting the application to work first before resolving any of those. But what I was thinking was that I would `delete` the array using the destructor later on in development. Do i have to delete each iteration of the Cell object after storing them in the array? Would this not affect the Object already stored in the Array? Thanks

Comment: think of boost as Java class library equivalent.  it has lots of functionality, avoiding it most likely is no productive.

Comment: @Kris: I see now from your original post that you're from a Java background.  When you do `Cell *currentCell = new Cell(...); ... cellList[rowIter][colIter] = *currentCell`, you're creating a new `Cell` object, and then copying its contents into an existing `Cell` object.  So you now have two objects, one of which is pointed to by `currentCell`.  As soon as you move to the next loop iteration, you lose track of the object pointed to by `currentCell`, which is the memory leak.  Quickest fix is to add `delete currentCell;` at the end of the loop body.

Comment: @Oli: Thanks for the help but why though? the call ` cellList[rowIter][colIter] = *currentCell` should store a pointer to the currentCell object in the Array index and NOT create a new one, or am I just being stupid? I believ you are right I just want to know why. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @Kris: No, this is unlike Java in this respect.  `Cell *a = new Cell(); Cell b; b = *a;` copies the contents of the object `*a` into the object `b`.  However, `Cell *a = new Cell(); Cell *b; b = a;` copies only the pointer value; `b` and `a` now point to the same object.  To reduce the confusion, many C++ programmers prefix names of pointer variables with `p` or `ptr`, e.g. `Cell *pA = new Cell();`.

Comment: Thanks, Got it now. Will do some more reading on this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

As already stated in comments, you have a memory leak issue.

> if (currentArrayCell==NULL){   // This line throws an error ->No match for ‘operator==’ in ‘currentArrayCell == 0’. Why?

`currentArrayCell` as declared in your code is a `Cell` object. Not a pointer to one. So you aren't comparing if a pointed to Cell is NULL. That line is trying to compare if a Cell == 0. And since you apparently haven't defined an equality operator that could work with a Cell and 0 the compiler raises that error.

With that in mind, you should note that the line `Cell currentArrayCell = cellArr[column];`
 is actually creating a copy of a Cell. It may not be important this time. But if you write similar code where you would modify `currentArrayCell`, then you would find that any changes are only made to the local copy and not to the element in `cellArr`.

This line:

```
printf("%s(%s)|", currentArrayCell.getWeight(),currentArrayCell.getValue());
```

is most likely not doing what you wanted. `s%` means you must pass a string (meaning something like a `const char*`). However, based on your other code I'm guessing that those member functions are returning integers. `printf` is a low level tool and does not have the ability to convert between data types in that manner. You either need to use the appropriate format specifier for the data type (such as `%d` for int) or convert the values before passing them to `printf`.

So what happens when you use the wrong format specifier is that `printf` tries to byte-wise interpret whatever you actually passed as whatever type the format specifier implies. In your case, it's trying to interpret integers as character pointers. I'm actually surprised this isn't causing a crash instead of just printing nulls.

Comment: Most of your ideas seem quite sound, I will try them out and get back to you with the results.

Comment: I have accepted the answer as this `printf` problem was partly the problem. Apparently passing an integer argument to printf when it is expecting a String will return a null as  output. The main problem apparently stemmed from the 'for'  loop and the lack of initializer in it. Once I added the initialisers into the `for` loop everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

just to give you an idea

```
template<typename T>
struct array {
    array(int m, int n) {
        size_[0] = m, size_[1] = n;
        data_.resize(m*n);
    }
    T* operator[](int i) {
        return &data_.front() + i*size_[1];
    }
private:
    stdvector<T> data_;
    size_t size_[2];
};
```

Comment: Thanks , even though your solution looks very interesting ( are you f
creating some sort of custom array?) but I would really want to know why the above code returned nulls. It would help my learning process. But Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It seems clear from your code that you're a C guy doing C++, so here are some classes that should be aware of in light of your goals.

[Boost's ublas](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) has a matrix implementation that would be a generally superior alternative to creating your own implementation.

Baring that, at bare minimum you should probably be working with [vectors](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html) instead of dynamically created arrays to reduce the potential for memory leaks.